# Produce table of contents and Page numbering with proper place

Tags: table-of-contents, packages, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I'm trying to write my thesis. I  have two questions.

1. Contents should be as shown on the photo. I highlighted the places where I had difficulty.

a) All the things must not be bold.

b) "Contents" has to be

- in the middle of the page
- 3 cm below the top
- not bold
- written in a different language just say ABCDEF image description is added.

c) "Pages" should be written on the numbers.

d) There must be some points between "Chapters" and "numbers".

e) There must be a point after number befeore  Chapter like after "1": "1. A....................33"

f) The `\frontmatter` materials like `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables` have to be seen in different language just say A, B.

2. One of the thesis writing rules, "page layout" should be as seen in the photo. There will be no head no foot. A4 paper (210mm x 297mm) will be used. The main text will be inside the rectangle inside. Except for placing the page number, I did the rest with the following command.

> ```
> \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
> \usepackage{geometry}
> \geometry{
>   a4paper,
>   total={210mm,297mm},
>   left=27.5mm,
>   top=0mm, right=27.5mm, bottom=20mm}
> ```

But I did not put the page numbers proper place.

[The figures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cCOO.png)

Answer (score 0):

The general rule here is that you only ask one question at a time but you have asked seven! You haven't provided an MWE that shows what you have tried except for your `\geometry` specification which results in warnings which I assume you have not tried to eliminate.

Use the `tocloft` package for the ToC (LoF and LoT) layouts.

```
% thesistocprob.tex  SE 576459

%%% this is your MWE

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
      a4paper,
      total={210mm,297mm},
      left=27.5mm,
      top=0mm, right=27.5mm, bottom=20mm}

%%%% and so ends your MWE (which gives warnings about your geometry specification)

\usepackage{tocloft}
% change the tableofcontents title, new name, center and Pages
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{ABCDEF}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large} 
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill\mbox{}\\ \mbox{}\hfill Pages}
% Don't bold chapter titles
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{}
% add a dot after chapter number
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
% use a dotted leader for chapter entries
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\chapter{First}
\section{First section}

\begin{figure}
\centering
ILLUSTRATION
\caption{An illustration}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I don't use the `geometry` package so fixing your document layout is up to you. The `book` class by default assumes `twoside,openright` so delete these from you `\documentclass[...]{book}`.

In my MWE I have shown how to get the ToC to look like what I think you are after. I leave it up to you to tweak your LoF and LoT. I must admit that I had the feeling that you were asking someone to write your thesis for you. --- GOM

Comment: After reading this:"I must admit that I had the feeling that you were asking someone to write your thesis for you." I must admit that I feel you have no idea what the thesis is.

Comment: I'm very new here (log in here almost 3 hours ago). So I don't know the general rules. If you don't like this question at all, just click minus and keep going. You don't have to answer.

Comment: @S.S.Danyal My apologies. I have no idea what your thesis is about but had grave doubts that you know how to produce a LaTeX thesis. Forgive me for being a sarcastic Grumpy Old Man.

Comment: Ok.  No problem. So far, I just used always default style in Latex. I do not know how to produce new style. Now, after your answer, I try to learn it from this book: "LaTeX Beginner's  ( Stefan Kottwitz)" . By the way, thank you for your answer.